# Unhide multiple elements with onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, element

I have code working on my site that when someone clicks the content of a row in a table, more content appears. That works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //hide the all of the element with class abstract
    $("..meetings-list .meeting_title_and_description .abstract").hide();
    //toggle the componenet with class meetingname
    $("..meetings-list .meeting_title_and_description .meeting_name").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".meetings-list .meeting_title_and_description .abstract").slideToggle(50);
     });
});
```

However, now i want to make a second element to appear as well on the same onclick event. I can't figure out how to code that. I tried something like this, but it didn't work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //hide the all of the element with class abstract
    $("..meetings-list .meeting_title_and_description .abstract").$("..meetings-list .meeting_title_and_description .secondthingtohide").hide();
    //toggle the componenet with class meetingname
    $("..meetings-list .meeting_title_and_description .meeting_name").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".meetings-list .meeting_title_and_description        .    abstract").$("..meetings-list .meeting_title_and_description .abstract").$("..meetings-list .meeting_title_and_description .secondthingtohide").slideToggle(50);
     });
});
```

Anybody an idea?

Comment: live site is here, www.biomeeter.com/twee_index.php

Answer (score 0):

Try using wildcard selector approach for this one, such as this:

```
$("[.^=meeting]").toggle();
 // OR //
$("[class^=meeting]").hide();
```

[class^=meeting] or [.^=meeting] tells jQuery to select all tags with the class ***starting*** with 'meeting', and toggle them all with whichever function you want (i.e. show(), hide(), fadeIn(), fadeOut(), and such).

```
$("[.$=meeting]").show();
 // OR //
$("[class$=meeting]").fadeOut();
```

[class$=meeting] or [.$=meeting] tells jquery to select all tags with the class ***ending*** with 'meeting', and toggle them all with whichever function you want (i.e. show(), hide(), fadeIn(), fadeOut(), and such).

Comment: Hi Faron, i used your method. www.biomeeter.com/twee_index2.php. It works for 1 element, but not the second. Somehow, it stays hidden

Comment: {
  //hide the all of the element with class abstract
  $("[class^=showthis]").hide();
  //toggle the componenet with class meetingname
  $("..meetings-list .meeting_title_and_description .meeting_name").click(function()
  {
    $(this).next("[class^=showthis]").slideToggle(50);
  });
});

Comment: For a specific elements to my own liking, I give these elements with id names and then I can manipulate these elements without classes interfering.

Comment: Ok, and how would you define that then? Say i have an element id=1 and element id=2?

Comment: To do the selecting with id as an element, use this: $("[#^=meeting]").toggle(); (above suggestion is for class as an element).

Assign your desired divs to be manipulated with this format for id:
<div id="meeting_1"></div> <div id="meeting_2"></div> and go on.